# What is the best practise in using TFS database

Tags: tfs

When I am trying to Install TFS it is asking me to "Install new SQL server" or "Use the existing SQL server". If I have existing SQL server which is used by the Application ( all the application related tables ,SP..etc) and if I choose to select the "use the existing data base" while installing TFS. Will that effect in the performance of the application? Because application uses the same database as well Tiffs also uses the same database.

Wondering if some one can suggest me what is the best practice to use the same data base which is used by application or use the different database for TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  if you have two applications using the same database server you will likely have a performance impact, dependent on capacity/performance of the servers.

I would recommend that you instead create an account on http://tfs.visualstudio.com and use the hosted TFS. It's more secure, has backups, and is supported and managed by Microsoft for you. You get 5 users included over and above any MSDN users that you already have.

If you are intent on running your own server then TFS included a SQL Server standard license if you are running on a single server, and only use it for TFS. So I would install SQL Standard and then TFS 2017 and select Existing. If you get TFS to install its own SQL it will use Express...